# Create a Public_HTML folder and direct visits to it?

Tags: dns

I'm trying to do the transition from a regular hosting to a dedicated server but I don't know how to set up a public_HTML folder so that my IP redirects to it by default .

I created a directory called Public_HTML on the root.

How could all visits to the IP to it? I believe it's done with a DNS A record or such, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your "regular hosting" uses Apaches [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html), to serve files. This meens, you  have a folder beneath your users' home (or whatever is configured), called "public_html".

If you want to switch over to your dedicated server, you have to install a webserver first, you can't just create a "public_html" folder and the files get served!

If you installed a webserver, your HTML-files are going to the configured document_root of your website. If you use Apache, this is by default /var/www/ (Debian/Ubuntu).

Every folder you create beneath /var/www will be accessible via "yourdomain.com/folder".

Your Domain A-Record has to point to the new server of course! To achive this, your provider usually has an interface, to configure DNS. If you can not configure your DNS by yourself, ask your hosting provider for help.